Yield Curve Modelling - 2Y10Y Differential
Is there a standard way to model yield curve differentials (e.g. the 2Y10Y)? I was thinking about it like this.
Let $L_t$ be the level of the 2Y10Y. Let $r_t = L_t - L_{t-1}$ be the change in the 2Y10Y from $t-1$ to $t$. Intuition says that when the yield curve is inverted, i.e. $L_t < 0$, then $r_t$ should have a positive expected value $\mu_{r_t}$ (since we an inverted yield curve is an anomaly, and we the inversion to go away), and the distribution should be right-skewed, since we don't expect a large further negative changes in the 2Y10Y, but large positive changes are possible.
In short, I was thinking about fitting two skew-$t$ distributions to $r_t$, one for when $L_t<0$ and one for when $L_t>0$.
What do you think of this? Are there any standard ways to model the 2Y10Y (or any other) differential?
-Michael
